# Facebook API: how to paginate comments

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I use facebook-sdk witn Python 3 http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

I can paginate posts by time:

```
paging_next = gp.get_connections(url, 'feed', until=timestamp_until_list[1], **kwargs)['paging']['next']
```

But comments doesn't have until, they have ['paging']['cursors']['after'] and ['paging']['cursors']['before'].
when i try to get next

```
paging_next = gp.get_connections(id=post_id, connection_name='comments', limit=100, **kwargs)['paging']['cursors']['after']  # this working, result is 'MQZDZD'
```

then i pass 'MQZDZD':

```
paging_next2 = gp.get_connections(id=post_id, connection_name='comments', after=paging_next, **kwargs)
```

result is empty list []

What i am doing wrong?